# Hide a method in springdoc-openapi based on a condition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-ui

We are working on a spring boot project which uses the springdoc-openapi library to generate the swagger document. We have a requirement where we need to hide a few of the APIs in a controller.
Spring boot does provide a way to hide/show a controller using the @ConditionalOnProperty tag. but spring boot does not have a way to hide/show a method based on property.

Does springdoc-openapi provide a way to filter the operation after scanning all controllers? or any other way to hide/show some APIs on swagger based on a property.

Answer (score 3):

You can override springdoc'S OperationService#isHidden behavior like that:

```java
package alex.swaggerhidden.service;

import org.springdoc.core.GenericParameterService;
import org.springdoc.core.OperationService;
import org.springdoc.core.PropertyResolverUtils;
import org.springdoc.core.RequestBodyService;
import org.springdoc.core.SecurityService;
import org.springdoc.core.providers.JavadocProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Optional;


@Component
@Primary
public class MyOperationService extends OperationService {

    private final boolean exposeHidden;

    
    public MyOperationService(GenericParameterService parameterBuilder, RequestBodyService requestBodyService, SecurityService securityParser, PropertyResolverUtils propertyResolverUtils, Optional<JavadocProvider> javadocProvider, @Value("${app.expose-hidden}") boolean exposeHidden) {
        super(parameterBuilder, requestBodyService, securityParser, propertyResolverUtils, javadocProvider);
        this.exposeHidden = exposeHidden;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isHidden(Method method) {
        if (exposeHidden) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.isHidden(method);

    }
}
```

Now hidden behavior will be ignored if `app.expose-hidden` set to `TRUE`

```yaml
app:
  expose-hidden: true
```